# How to rbind many (+1000) *.rds files fast

Tags: r

I have over 2000 *.rds files that are 18,000 obs and I would like to merge them all into one `data.frame`.  I know it's not efficient to grow objects with `for` loops and have done so, but is taking really long as it progresses.  Is there a faster way to do this?

Here are a couple of things I've tried so far:

`lapply`:

```
mergedat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files("dat/"), readRDS))
```

`for` loop:

```
files <- list.files("dat/")
merged <- data.frame()
for (i in unique(files)){
df <- readRDS(paste0("dat/", i))
merged <- rbind(merged, df)
}
```

Comment: In some extremes, quoting the function might be faster (ala `do.call("rbind", ...`). In this case, though, have you tried `dplyr::bind_rows`? In my tests (using small data.frames), it runs almost an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: @r2evans I have not tried `dplyr` option; I guess I'll give that a go too.

Comment: `data.table::rbindlist` would also be worth checking out.

Comment: @Gregor This was it.  It merged everything in less than a minute with `rbind` took over 20.  thanks!

Comment: FYI, the first `do.call` is missing a trailing `)`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were close with your first attempt.  With a slight modifications, the following worked for me

```
mergedat <- do.call('rbind', lapply(list.files("dat/", full.names = TRUE), readRDS))
```

The only thing I added was `full.names = TRUE`.

Comment: OP didn't say it doesn't work. OP said it takes time to finish.

Comment: Thanks, but both of those I suggested work.  They just take a long time.  Any way to speed things up?

Comment: Ok, got it.  There was a typo in the original post, I will comment on it there.

Comment: Perhaps I should delete this answer and Gregor should move the suggestion to an "Answer" to get credit.

Comment: whoa this is an old post but you can use,  dplyr::bind_rows which is much faster.

Comment: @Ahdee yes, this is old, I forget about this question. Since this question is considered closed because an answer exists, I don't know if it is worth updating here. In addition to your suggestion, I have been using the following to quickly load many large data files (10s of millions of rows): `my.dt <- data.table::rbindlist(lapply(fnames, function(fn) data.table::fread(fn)))`. This code has run significantly faster than what I have previously done. I believe there may also be other options that are faster.

Comment: @steveb yes agree, data.table or the dplyr's bind_rows is so much faster. I was confused because of some weird thing that I needed to stich together >9K worth of dataframe and was surpise that after many hours it was still going.  with bin_rows it took less than 30 mins. thanks.

Comment: also the duplication alert is not correct since this is about speed and not so much about merging multiple tables.