# R – Summarizing content of sublists in nested list

Tags: r

I’ve been given a nested list where each sublist contains information about values of one specific data frame. The list has the following structure:

```
summary <- list(df1 = list(value1 = "phone", count = 11, ratio = 78.57, value2 = "mail", count = 13, ratio = 92.86, value3 = "zoom", count = 8, ratio = 57.14),
df2 = list(value4 = "yes", count = 4, ratio = 28.57, value5 = "no", count = 10, ratio = 71.43))

str(summary)
List of 2
 $ df1:List of 9
  ..$ value1: chr "phone"
  ..$ count : num 11
  ..$ ratio : num 78.6
  ..$ value2: chr "mail"
  ..$ count : num 13
  ..$ ratio : num 92.9
  ..$ value3: chr "zoom"
  ..$ count : num 8
  ..$ ratio : num 57.1
 $ df2:List of 6
  ..$ value4: chr "yes"
  ..$ count : num 4
  ..$ ratio : num 28.6
  ..$ value5: chr "no"
  ..$ count : num 10
  ..$ ratio : num 71.4
```

Here, `summary[[1]]` states that the value *“phone”* occurred eleven times in data frame 1 with a certain ratio, the value *“mail”* occurred 13 times and so on. The same applies for data frame 2 where *“yes”* was counted four times etc.

Now, i want to create a nested list, that summarizes for each sublist in *summary* the *values*, *counts*, and *ratios*. More precisely, each sublist of the *result* list should only consist of three elements *value*, *count* and *ratio*, each containing the values, corresponding counts and ratios. The desired list *result* should have the following structure:

```
result <- list(res_df1 = list(value = c("phone", "mail", "zoom"), count = c(11,13,8), ratio = c(78.57, 92.86, 57.14)),
res_df2 = list(value = c("yes", "no"), count = c(4, 10), ratio = c(28.57, 71.43)))

str(result)
List of 2
 $ res_df1:List of 3
  ..$ value: chr [1:3] "phone" "mail" "zoom"
  ..$ count: num [1:3] 11 13 8
  ..$ ratio: num [1:3] 78.6 92.9 57.1
 $ res_df2:List of 3
  ..$ value: chr [1:2] "yes" "no"
  ..$ count: num [1:2] 4 10
  ..$ ratio: num [1:2] 28.6 71.4
```

I’ve come up with a solution, that produces this outcome but it feels more like a workaround and not a quite nice R solution:

```
library(rlist)
result <- list()
for(i in 1:length(summary)){
    tmp <- (summary[[i]])
    value <- as.character(tmp[seq(1, length(tmp), 3)])
    count <- as.numeric(tmp[seq(2, length(tmp), 3)])
    ratio <- as.numeric(tmp[seq(3, length(tmp), 3)])
    df <- cbind.data.frame(value, count, ratio)
    result <- list.append(result, df)
}
```

I couldn’t come up with a working solution which contains for example a *lapply* approach or similar. Is there a nicer, more compact way to do this? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like that?

```
for (i in 1:3) {
   idx <- seq(i, length(summary[[1]]), 3)
   assign(paste0("new",i), lapply(summary[[1]][idx], "[[", 1) )
 }
data.table::rbindlist(list(new1, new2, new3))
```

If you do this for every sublist (perhaps exchanging the index i with a max_length instead of 3. This is a more R approach. We use lapply, [[, and in the end the very fast `rbindlist` from the `data.table package` (I put it in there just to highlight that it comes from this package)

That gives you:

```
   value1 value2 value3
1:  phone   mail   zoom
2:     11     13      8
3:  78.57  92.86  57.14
```

This rbindlist approach is also very scalable as you can see in this post:

> [How to rbind many (+1000) *.rds files fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604869/how-to-rbind-many-1000-rds-files-fast)

because it can bind a lot of files/lists much faster than append or rbind

Comment: thank you, that's a nice approach! I've added `use.names = FALSE` to avoid the error of missing column (names).